# Why my django project not runing on ngnix?

Tags: django, nginx, deployment

I'm trying to run my django project on subdomain, my nginx configuration is,

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name subdomain.example.me www.subdomain.example.me;

location /static/ {
        root /home/gagan/webmash/blog;
}


location /media/ {
        root /home/gagan/webmash/blog;
}


location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass  http://my_ip:9000;
}
```

}
While my supervisor configuration is,

```
[program:webmash]
command=/home/gagan/webmash/env/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/gagan/webmash /blog/blog.sock blog.wsgi --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=blog.settings.production
 directory=/home/gagan/webmash/blog
 autostart=true
 autorestart=true
 stderr_logfile=/var/log/saporawebapp.err.log
 stdout_logfile=/var/log/saporawebapp.out.log
```

when i run supervisor using,

```
sudo supervisorctl restart webmash
```

It doesn't show any error. On restarting nginx, it too doesn't show any error.But my project is not runing either at https://subdomain.example.com or my_ip:9000.
What can be the possible causes for such behaviour

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Nginx with systemd over supervisor. 
Here's a tutorial to leave Django running with Nginx + Gunicorn + Systemd + AnaConda.

Maybe my github here will help you:

[Githhub/Nginx](https://github.com/Nouvellie/ubuntu/blob/ubuntu/contents/nginx.md)